# Jasper reports & JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jasper-reports

```
14:19:51,593 ERROR [STDERR] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:4: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:5: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;
^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:13: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:15: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*;
^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol: class JRCalculator
public class ceCertificateTemplate extends JRCalculator
                                           ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_LOCALE = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_SCRIPTLET = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_CONNECTION = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_DATA_SOURCE = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:35: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_DATECREATEDON = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_LINE_ONE_ADDR = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_CREDITHRS = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_NAME = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_PSTL_CD = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_ROSTERDETAIL_COMPDATE = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_ST_CD = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_DATECREDITSREPORTED = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:43: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_PROVIDERNAMEANDNUMBER = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_ENTASSOC_APPROVALNO = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_IL_INDV_ID = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:46: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillField field_PARENT_FNAME = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillVariable variable_PAGE_NUMBER = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:49: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillVariable variable_COLUMN_NUMBER = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:50: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillVariable variable_REPORT_COUNT = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillVariable variable_PAGE_COUNT = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
    private JRFillVariable variable_COLUMN_COUNT = null;
            ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:62: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRException
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
        ) throws JRException
                 ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:64: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
        parameter_REPORT_LOCALE = (JRFillParameter)parsm.get("REPORT_LOCALE");
                                   ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:64: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable parsm
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
        parameter_REPORT_LOCALE = (JRFillParameter)parsm.get("REPORT_LOCALE");
                                                   ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:65: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
        parameter_REPORT_SCRIPTLET = (JRFillParameter)parsm.get("REPORT_SCRIPTLET");
                                      ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:65: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable parsm
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
        parameter_REPORT_SCRIPTLET = (JRFillParameter)parsm.get("REPORT_SCRIPTLET");
                                                      ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:66: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
        parameter_REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP = (JRFillParameter)parsm.get("REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP");
                                           ^
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\ceCertificateTemplate.java:66: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable parsm
location: class ceCertificateTemplate
        parameter_REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP = (JRFillParameter)parsm.get("REPORT_PARAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not including some of the jars in classpath.

[package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist](http://www.coderanch.com/t/274055/open-source/package-net-sf-jasperreports-engine)